# Skip / filter out lines with specified strings in it

Tags: powershell

I need to filter one or more lines out of a .csv ...
In the example below I try to filter out the line with 'name' int it but it won't do that. Anybody any Idea why?

```
($csv = Import-Csv .\file.csv -Delimiter ',' -Header " ") | Where-Object {
    ($_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Value
    }) -ne 'name'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Import-Csv .\file.csv |?{$_ -notmatch "name"}
```

for multiple values it will be simplier with a regex :

```
[regex]$exclude="name|---" 
(Import-Csv .\file.csv) -notmatch $exclude
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Can I also compare more than only name? Like I want to ignore "name" and "----".

Comment: Thanks ! Sorry that I ask soo much but is it also possible to remove all empty lines in that CSV also ?

Comment: try this `(Import-Csv .\file.csv) -notmatch $exclude | ?{$_.PSObject.Properties.Value -ne ""}  `. If you have powershell V2 it would be `(Import-Csv .\file.csv) -notmatch $exclude | ?{ ($_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {$_.Value}) -ne ""}`

Comment: I have PS V1. I tried this but it did not do anything to the output
`($csv = Import-Csv .\file1.csv -Delimiter ',' -Header " ") | ? {
   ($_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Value
   }) -notmatch "$exclude" | ?  {$_.PSObject.Properties.Value -ne ""}`